# How can I make this effect with lines in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, grids, transform, line-art, skew

[image]I tried scale and shear, but dont know how to smake this effect

Answer (score 4):

- Draw a rectangle as large as you want your grid
- Apply a **stroke and *no fill*** to the rectangle
- With this rectangle selected, choose `Object > Path > Split into grid` and enter the number of rows and columns you want...
  [image]
  ... and click <kbd>OK</kbd>
- With the grid still selected, choose `Object > Envelope Distort > Make With Mesh` 
  enter an amount for rows/columns again in *this* dialog. These will be rows and columns for *distortion*. After you do this a couple times you'll get the hang of how these mesh rows/column work. They are different than the grid rows/columns. When you have a few divisions (you only need a few - you *don't* need the same amount that you entered for the grid), and click <kbd>OK</kbd> for the Mesh dialog window.
- You now have a grid inside a mesh container. If you distort the mesh, you'll distort the grid....
- Merely move the resulting mesh points and handles around...

[image]